# How to use Composer with git pull so that class not found does not comes

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

I am using Laravel 5.6.

My Current Code deployment process is as follow

1. Made some changes to file
2. Commit and push it to branch.
3. Once everything is perfect merge it to master and pull master branch to code production server(Where my code is).

My Issue

1. If I have some dependencies which is maintained by composer. I just add it to current branch and made changes to other files.
2. When I merge it with master and pull it to production server I need to run composer update command manually.
3. Server gives errors when we try to access it that it dependencies class or service provider not found(As we need to add it to config/app.php in Laravel) When it is updating composer dependencies.
4. After updating it is working perfectly.
5. So I want to avoid that 5-10 sec error which comes while updating composer dependencies.

I have two options

1. Put Application on maintenance mode while updating code. -> I cannot do that.
2. Every time whenever there is dependencies upload it using two merge. -> I Don't want to do that.

Is there any other best practices solutions to this problem so that we can avoid such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never update on the production server, just composer install. You can hook this to your merge git action, accordingly to how you deploy to production (CI/CD, scripting or all manual?). Here documentation for git hooks: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks
this is for git-hooks post-merge: https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_post_merge

Answer (score 0):

*When I merge it with master and pull it to production server I need to run composer update command manually.*

No you dont. You should only run

```
> composer install
```

on the live server to make sure composers dependancies are up to date with changes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to deploy to avoid this problem is that each time you deploy, you do so to a new folder. Then, once the deployment is complete, you switch the folder.

This could be done using a symlink, or similar:

```
deploys
    1551270000
    1551280000
live > deploys/1551280000
```

Then make a new deployment (`1551290000`):

```
deploys
    1551270000
    1551280000
    1551290000
live > deploys/1551280000
```

Then when it’s finished, change the symlink:

```
deploys
    1551270000
    1551280000
    1551290000
live > deploys/1551290000
```

This is what [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/) and others do. I would recommend using a tool like that rather than trying to write your own – this problem has already been solved.